# If I know how many lines to go down, how do I know where to start in the file in terms of bytes

Tags: linux, osx, read

I want start `read()`'ing a file at a certain position. I know how many lines to start reading at - but read() doesn't take lines as an argument, it takes bytes for position.

Is there some trick I can use to calculate what position to start reading at, if I know which line to start reading at?

Comment: I assume "trick" means more than "read the bytes and count `\n`s"? If there is an answer it will be platform-dependent, so you'd need to [edit] in your target platform(s).

Comment: If you're not interested in the line number, you can start reading anywhere and go backwards and forwards until you have a whole line. But it's quite normal to read the entire file, and re-write the entire file too. There is no byte <-> line number mapping unless you maintain one yourself...

Comment: Note, there are library functions on top of `read()` to simplify this sort of common problem. Check out `fgets()` to read "lines". It is part of the stdio library, but you will need to study it a bit to become familier with it before use. And it is always good to understand what is going on underneath the library calls.

Answer (score 0):

There can't be any trick. Skipping bytes is simple, because you can calculate the position in the file where to start. But you can't calculate with lines of variable length without checking for each character whether it is a line break.

Think of a book: When you want to find page 42, you can count the pages until 42 without even looking at it. For well defined page thickness, you could even use a ruler to measure where page 42 is. But if you want to find chapter five, you need to look at all pages the see where a new chapter starts.

A file has no line index, so even if there was some line-skip implementation, behind the surface there is no other chance than reading byte by byte to find the lines, so you can as well `read` all lines and drop the ones you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

You read all the bytes and count how many times byte 10 (`\n`) appears. Its *n*th appearance immediately precedes the *n*+1th line.

This is not a trick, unfortunately, but just the only viable approach.

There **are** [record-oriented filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record-oriented_filesystem) on some platforms that may allow direct seeking by line (for example, [on VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_Management_Services) and [z/OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_Record_Data_Set)), but those filesystems are not common on either of your platforms. Unix and POSIX envisage files just as byte streams, and do not provide any further abstraction themselves on top of that.